# How to correct this test case in mocha framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I am trying to write test case for node application, which is using mocha as test framework.

**test.js**

```
var register = require('../routes/users');
var request = require('request');
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

describe('registerUser()', function() {

    it('check email is already registered', function (done) {
        request.post({uri:baseUrl+'/register', form :{
            username: 'test',
            email: 'test@test.com'
        }}, function (e, res, body) {
            res.should.have.property('statusCode', 201);
            res.should.have.property('regErr', 'This email is already taken!');
        })
    });

})
```

The `regErr` is given as parameter in function `registerUser` on render. I expected the parameter`regErr` will be set as property of response and can be get in test.
Please check my [registerUser function](https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management/blob/master/routes/users.js#L117-L119) in github.
I am trying create a test case for this function.

Above code doesn't have property called `regErr` in response fetched in test case.

How to correct so that the rendering parameters can also be property in response?

Shall I need to change the actual function `registerUser` to get this? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to log e, res, and body? I have never used request, but I think this is usually set in e.body or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing an HTTP request, the callback function is called with three arguments:

- err (Possible error return)
- res (HTTPRequest object)
- body (Buffer of the resulting body)

Therefore, regErr is in the body variable. And since you are rendering an HTML page, you're gonna have to parse the body yourself to find it. A possible solution would be to render JSON and use JSON.parse() on the resulting body buffer.

Comment: How to parse the body variable? The body variable contains whole html elements of the page. If I need to pass JSON, then I should need send response `res.json({..})`. Then how can I render the whole html elements in page?

Comment: @JustinJohn: You can parse it with Regexes, but a more ideal option would be to replace your res.render with res.json when launching the server in "unit-testing" mode.